# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS throws an error in UCanAccess

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

Instead of using MySQL xampp server on my Java project, I decided to use Microsoft Access as my database but I got an error in my query using this syntax. Here is my Java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Database.accdb;jackcessOpener=myproject.CryptCodecOpener","root", "");
            System.out.println("successfuly connected");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement state = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(name varchar(400))");
            state.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
     finally {

        }
```

Here is the error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: IF
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:256)
    at myproject.MyProject.main(MyProject.java:31)
```

Using `IF NOT EXISTS` in MySQL works fine, but in UCanAccess I got that error and if I remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` it works fine.

Comment: do you have enough privileges to create a table in the database?

Comment: Why don't you simply use HSQLDB directly?

Comment: yes. if I remove the IF NOT EXISTS like this **CREATE TABLE TEST("name varchar(250)")**, it works fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean by that? sorry but im new in this libraries

Comment: If you are programming in Java, why not use a Java embedded database? UCanAccess is just a wrapper to make MS Access databases accessible through JDBC - and it uses HSQLDB internally for processing the SQL statements. If don't really need MS Access and just want an embedded database in your Java application use HSQLDB directly or H2. Both DBMS are much more powerful then MS Access and will give you a lot less problems

Comment: I am using UCanAccess to use MS Access as my database because of some reason..

Answer (score 3):

UCanAccess simply does not support `IF NOT EXISTS` in DDL statements. You should be able to do something like this instead:

```java
try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
    s.execute("CREATE TABLE test (name TEXT(50))");
} catch (UcanaccessSQLException ex) {
    if (ex.getMessage().indexOf("object name already exists:") > 0) {
        System.out.println("INFO: Table already exists.");
    } else {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```